# Javascript Date shows the wrong value when using alert

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript is creating date wrong month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254333/javascript-is-creating-date-wrong-month)

In my code, I create `Date` by this line:

```
var date = new Date('2012', '01', '20')
```

and then using:

```
alert(date);
```

I get the result:

[image]

I don't really understand why not Jan instead of Feb?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U5m8N/

Comment: Month parameter is 0 based, not 1. January is 0, February is 1. See [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Also, the parameters should be integers, not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Month" part of `var date = new Date('2012', '01', '20');` is zero-indexed.

Start counting at `0`, and you got your month. (So, January is `0`, Feb `1`, etc.)

Also, while JavaScript does accept strings as parameters, you should be using integers, as the documentation suggests:

**[Date Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)**

Comment: [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)  is such a great link +1

Answer (score -1):

Javascript Date Object's Month is 0 indexed. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp. put 0 instead of 1 for Jan

Comment: [W3fools](http://www.w3fools.com), that site is full of mistakes.