# date fields of JavaScript not alerting the correct dates

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the Date field of JavaScript as below

```
var dateFrom = new Date(2013,02,03,00,00,00,00); 
var dateTo = new Date(2014,03,01,23,59,59,00);  
alert (dateFrom); 
alert(dateTo);
```

These are not giving the correct dates.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which dates do you get and which do you expect?

Comment: @FelixKling - Dilbert is getting the wrong dates, and he's expecting to get the right dates! Jeezes, it's right there in the question?

Comment: @adeneo: I'm so sorry, I cannot read.

Comment: @FelixKling - Well now you know, something is wrong that needs to be right, we don't really need to know any more do we.

Comment: @adeneo: :( It won't happen again, please don't yell at me.

Comment: @adeneo Well you two so funny, in one question, happening!

Comment: @dollarvar - Nope, we're dead serious. All questions should just be "something is wrong, please fix", and we'll just figure out the rest ourselves.

Comment: @adeneo: Can I use my crystal ball? Or is that against the rules?

Comment: @adeneo Nooo, you cannot do that? Test cases for work are always like this.

Comment: @FelixKling - Doesn't everyone use a crystal ball, don't think there's any rules against that?

Comment: @FelixKling Use the console, like in Star Trek, wormhole!

Comment: @adeneo: OK, let me try it.... oh I think I know!

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript is creating date wrong month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254333/javascript-is-creating-date-wrong-month)

Comment: (^^^ if that's actually not your problem, you know what you have to do)

Comment: @dollarvar: Wormholes are dangerous, I'm not going to play around with those :P

Comment: @FelixKling - Man, that's some crystal ball, wish I had one like that, mine just randomly spits out gibberish that I keep posting on this site. I followed your ball(s) advice and voted for the same !

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable inputs. Dilbert will try to less dilbertish and more inputish when asking future question. Thanks and I have learnt why the error happened . Date field starts from zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Months start from index `0`**.

You surely expect:  3 February and 1 March
But you got:  3 March and 1 April

Try this:

```
var dateFrom = new Date(2013,1,3,0,0,0,0); 
var dateTo = new Date(2014,2,1,23,59,59,0);  
alert (dateFrom); 
alert(dateTo);
```

Comment: If that is indeed the problem (which it most likely is) then it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12254333/218196