# Jquery UI Datepicker adds a month to minDate and maxDate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, maxdate, mindate

I have a Jquery `UI datepicker` on my site, but when i choose `minDate` and `maxDate` it adds a month to each variable, why is that and how do i fix it?

```
var startDate = new Date(2014, 2, 24);
var endDate = new Date(2014, 3, 24);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2e7rT/13/)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript is creating date wrong month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254333/javascript-is-creating-date-wrong-month)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you date is taken from the database the easiest way to do so

```
var startDate = new Date(2014, 2, 24);
var endDate = new Date(2014, 3, 24);

startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth()-1);
endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth()-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

In `javascript`, month count start from 0 and ends to 11 like:

```
0-Jan
1-Feb
2-Mar
3-Apr
4-May
5-Jun
6-Jul
7-Aug
8-Sep
9-Oct
10-Nov
11-Dec
```

Answer (score 2):

The month is zero-based, so add 1 to your chosen dates.

e.g.

```
var yourDate = new Date(2014, 3, 24); //would be 24 April 2014
```