# Why is February, month 2, showing it has 31 days in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

Javascript is reporting that February has 31 days.  The code below shows that the second month has more days than it should.  What's going on?

```js
    var currentDate = new Date(2018, 2, 4);

    function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
      var date = new Date(year, month, 1);
      var days = [];
      while (date.getMonth() === month) {
        days.push(new Date(date));
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      }
      return days;
    }

    var dayArr = getDaysInMonth(currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getFullYear());
    alert('month: '+currentDate.getMonth()+' year: '+currentDate.getFullYear()+' days: '+dayArr.length);
```

Comment: `Date(2018, 2, 4)` is March 4. In JavaScript months are zero-based

Comment: There is no need for a Fiddle. Just include your code in a code snippet right here in your question.

Comment: 1 = feb........

Comment: If this is for a production script (not just an exercise), you might want to consider using a JS sate library (such as [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)), as they usually handle all the weird and unexpected behaviour for you.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of [*javascript is creating date wrong month*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254333/javascript-is-creating-date-wrong-month) (or any of the many other duplicates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because months are 0 indexed, so month 2 in JS is March.  Try it with,

var currentDate = new Date(2018, 1, 4);

That will output 28 days.

Comment: Uh, this is correct.  Why a downvote?

Comment: Not my down vote, but there are [plenty of duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+wrong+month) to choose from.