# JavaScript newDate(Date.UTC) Results in the Wrong Month

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs, utc

JavaScript is determined to ensure I get the wrong date.

I have UTC dates from the server. If I take the first one, it looks like this: `2021-03-09 19:00:00`.

My chart takes a date object. So I want to convert from UTC. The **correct** answer is:

-`Tue Mar 09 2021 12:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)`

Here is an insane overcoded attempt to force the right answer:

```
// given inputDate from the server
let re: RegExp = /{regular expression parsing date}/;
let m: RegExpMatchArray = inputDate.match(re);
let yyyy: number = Number(m[1]); // 2021
let mm: number = Number(m[2]);   // 3
let dd: number = Number(m[3]);   // 9
let hh: number = Number(m[4]);   // 19
let utc: number = Date.UTC(yyyy, mm, dd, hh);
let utcDate: Date = new Date(utc);

console.log('interp', `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd} ${hh}:00:00`);
console.log('utcDate', utcDate.toISOString());
```

Result:

```
interp 2021-3-9 19:00:00
utcDate 2021-04-09T19:00:00.000Z
```

*Am I going insane?* **Why** did it add a month??

Moment works so I guess I can stomach the extra 70KB:

```
let tryUtc: Moment = moment(inputDate).utc(true);
console.log('local', tryUtc.toDate());   // bingo
```

I still want to know why the month got added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12254344/14909805

Comment: @BurdenKing Yes it does and there's a very special place in hell for the person who decided to start months at 0. Why not start days, years, hours, minutes at zero too? Then everything can be wrong.

Comment: @AndrewBenjamin some background can be found here if you're curious ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552483/why-does-the-month-argument-range-from-0-to-11-in-javascripts-date-constructor

Comment: Parsing "2021-03-09 19:00:00" as UTC is 2 lines of code, you seriously do not need a library for that (e.g. `let [Y,M,D,H,m,s] = "2021-03-09 19:00:00".split(/\D/); let date = new Date(Date.UTC(Y,M-1,D,H,d,s))`.