# MongoVue date search adds 1 to month

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

Okay I am pretty sure this thing must be a bug... I have to enter the month previous to what I am looking for:

```
{
   "SportId":"Horse Racing",
   "Date":{$gt: new Date(2012,11,4)}
}
```

Explain output:

```
[ 15:21:39 ]
db.Fixture.find({ "SportId" : "Horse Racing", "Date" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2012-12-04T00:00:00Z") } }).limit(50);
db.Fixture.find({ "SportId" : "Horse Racing", "Date" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2012-12-04T00:00:00Z") } }).limit(50).explain();
```

Can anyone explain this - better than above? Not essential as now that I know I can work around it. But it seems like a pretty strange thing to happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The month is Zero based in the javascript Date constructor.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setmonth.asp

Comment: Wow. It's on purpose. I get it, but don't want to. Thanks for the info - more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453043/zero-based-month-numbering