# struct tm - Why days start at 1 whereas months start at 0?

Tags: java, c, date, time

As you can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) in `struct tm`, days are 1 indexed while months are 0 indexed.
The same can be seen in other languages like [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

What is the reason of doing this ?

The only purpose I can find is to make easier things like this :

```
const char *names[] = { "January", "February", ... };
names[date.tm_mon];
```

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar

Comment: @RayToal - not exactly, the other question only ask about the java implementation.

Comment: I suspect the answer is "just because".

Comment: @Andreas_D: I suspect Java simply inherited this from C ... - I mean, as Java is OO .. ;-)

Comment: But anyway, Jon's answer to the other (Java) question expands on C. http://stackoverflow.com/a/344400/105224

Comment: You may find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453043/zero-based-month-numbering