# System date is correct, but new Date() return wrong value

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

I have a strange problem.

My OS clock say we are the 12/09/2013, which is right, but when in a node.js app I do:

```
var time=new Date();
console.log(time.getDate()+'/'+time.getMonth()+'/'+time.getFullYear);
```

It print

```
12/08/2013
```

I don t know why it do that.

I could indeed do

```
var time.new Date();
time.setMonth(time.getMonth()+1);
```

But that would be a temporary trick, not a solution

Comment: Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: *The value returned by getMonth is an integer between 0 and 11. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.*

Comment: In other words, your temporary trick is indeed the proper solution.

Comment: It is indeed confusing, but thanks you.

Comment: Also, I ll accept answer of any of you if you post one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zero-based month numbering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453043/zero-based-month-numbering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the `getMonth()` function returns value starting from 0 to 11 and 0 denotes January and so on.