# Why does Javascript turn month 3 into April?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Now this seems kind of odd...

I have an array like this:

```
a = ["2014", "03", "12", "08", "43", "51"]
```

which I need to convert into a DateTime object. However:

```
new Date(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);
```

returns **Date {Sat Apr 12 2014 08:43:51 GMT+0200 (CEST)}**

**Question**
What happened to March?

Comment: Months are zero-based in Javascript, i.e. January is 0, April is 3.

Comment: 0-Jan, 1-Feb, 2-Mar, 3-Apr... etc.

Comment: @frequent: I know, right?

Comment: @MihaiScurtu: yup. voted to close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
a = ["2014", "02", "12", "08", "43", "51"]
```

We are starting counting [(only) month](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453095/2441442) at zero.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript uses 0 as January, 1 as February, so on till 11 as December. It is like array of of months from 0 to 11. Thats why it converts three as April

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, months in `Javascript` `date` are from 0 to 11 and not from 1 to 12