# Java DateFormat and SimpleDateFormat returning a date that is incorrect

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

Today is Tuesday, February 9, 2010 and when I print the date I get the wrong date:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date today = formatter.parse(String.format("%04d-%02d-%02d",
        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));

System.out.println("Today is " + today.toString());
```

The print line results in: "Today is Sat Jan 09 00:00:00 CST 2010"

It most certainly is not Saturday Jan 09, it's Tuesday Feb 09. I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong, so can anybody let me know what's wrong here? Do I have to manually set the day of week?

**Update**  
*Note: I don't want to initialize today with `new Date()` because I want the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds initialized to `0`.  This is necessary so I can compare a user input date with today: if the user inputs today's date and I use the formatter to construct a Date object, then if I initialize today with `new Date()` and I compare the two dates- today will be **after** the user selected date (which is incorrect).  Thus I need to initialize today at the beginning of the day without the hr/min/sec/ms.*

Comment: Why on earth would you get "today" that way?  Why not Date today = new Date()?  Your way is the long way and, as you can see, not even correct.

Comment: @duffymo  
It's in a JSP.  Suppose the user selects today as the day they want, then their input gets forwarded to another JSP.  The user input is recorded before I initialize today's date in the second jsp (with new Date() it initializes to the current time which is AFTER my user's input), so today will always be after the user selected date even though the user selected the same day. Thus I need to initialize today and keep the hr/min/sec/ms at 0.

Comment: Sounds like the second JSP should be parsing "today" from the first JSP's HTTP request, not calling "new Date".  If the answers are confused, it's because your question and requirements are as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Confusingly, Calendar months count from 0 (January) to 11 (December), so you're passing "2010-01-09" to formatter.parse() when you extract the MONTH field from the Calendar.

There's a discussion of this in a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use JodaTime you could use:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
calendar.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
calendar.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
calendar.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 );

Date today = calendar.getTime();
```

This is much more efficient and less error-prone than your String formatting/parsing approach.

If you can use JodaTime this is a much preferred method:

```
LocalDate date = new DateTime().toLocaleDate();
```

Comment: Thanks mtpettyp! That looks much better than what I had! :)