# Why does the month argument range from 0 to 11 in JavaScript's Date constructor?

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

When initializing a new `Date` object in JavaScript using the below call, I found out that the month argument counts starting from zero.

```
new Date(2010, 3, 1);  // that's the 1st April 2010!
```

Why does the month argument start from 0? On the other hand, the day of the month argument (last one) is a number from 1 to 31. Are there good reasons for this?

Comment: It is just to keep you on your toes.

Comment: One that is also zero indexed is `the Day of the week (integer)` 0-6

Comment: Because it was coded for machines and not for humans. But it is still a huge source of bugs because a lot of code is (still) written by humans :)

Comment: @Christophe the same argument should apply to day and year also.

Comment: @AgnelKurian, yes but it was probably coded by different humans :)

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy yeah, if it were coded for machines, why index days from 1 then?

Comment: [sarcasm] Because let's make it stupid. Why simplify it, right guys? [/sarcasm]

Comment: Good naming helps:  Rename "month" argument to "months_since_January".

Comment: Human: month is zero-based because it was coded for machines
Machine: umm, yeah, think I can handle it either way, remember that thing where I can do math millions of times faster than you?

Comment: The worst is when you have to use several modules for date for tech debt, and each module uses differently indexed months >:( Cost me 5 hours of debugging

Comment: ... clearly a bug ... trying to make sense of an obvious bug ... is a sign of stupid ... mark it as a bug ... and move on ... it's called an OBO bug ... off by one bug ... there is no reason the month should not follow the same indexing as day and year ... STUPID!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's an old (probably unfortunate, probably dying) tradition in the programming world, see the old standard (POSIX) *localtime* C function http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime

Comment: JS `Date` object was ported from Java 1.0, that's why. Inheriting all its flaws ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar

Comment: You are right, traditions are usually totally inconsistent and often times irrational and I would really hope that such "bad" traditions are really dying ...

Comment: is 2019 and I am fixing an issue related to this behaviour, so as long as frameworks as angular and languages as javascript dont deprecate this it will still happen - feel free to coment in the year 2025 and on ;-)

Comment: That's a tradition that always make me spend time on debugging issues with dates... Wondering how much millings of wasted working hours this tradition caused.

Comment: It's *never* going to change. There's an incomprehensibly vast amount of existing code that assumes this behavior. (I mean, in JavaScript.)

Comment: Potentially, we could get new retrieval functions that assume what we want to assume, with useful names, and deprecate the old ones. But changing the old ones would ruin everybody's day at this point.

Answer (score 237):

The real answer to this question, is that it was copied from `java.util.Date`, which also had this quirk.  Proof can be found on Twitter from Brendan Eich - the guy who originally implemented JavaScript:

https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/481939099138654209

[image: First Tweet, which says: "In case it helps (it doesn't for most), JS's Date is a copy of Java's JDK1.0 (1995) java.util.Date. Made it look like Java..."]

https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/771006397886533632

[image: Second Tweet, which says: "We were under "Make It Look Like Java" mgmt orders, and I had ten days to demo. No time to invent our own date API or even fix Java's."]

Brendan also indicates that it was Ken Smith of Netscape who did the porting from Java.

https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/771006208949891072

[image: Third Tweet, which says: "Only Mocha src file I didn't create was mo_date.c: Ken Smith of Netscape helped me translate java.util.Date from Java to C."]

This happened in 1995, and JDK 1.0 was in beta.  It launched in 1996.  In 1997, JDK 1.1 came out which deprecated the vast majority of functions on `java.util.Date`, moving them over to `java.util.Calendar`, but even that still had zero-based months.  Developers fed-up with this created the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, which ultimately led to `java.time` package that's baked in to Java 8 (2014).

In short, it took 18 years for Java to get a correctly designed date/time API built-in, but JavaScript is still stuck back in the dark ages.  We do indeed have excellent libraries like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/), [js-joda](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/), and others.  But as of now, there is nothing more than `Date` built-in to the language.  Hopefully this will change in the near future with [the TC39 Temporal proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/).

Comment: Ah... Good old Demo-Driven Development methodology.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I would blame original JDK 1.0 developer who introduced it in the first place.

Comment: @barell Why would you blame the guy who modeled the very first version of Java, there is no language that got it all figured out since the first version. Java actually corrected their Date api but Javascript are still stuck to the old one, javascript devs should at least give us a new api just like Java did introducing LocalDate.

Comment: @Yassir - That work is underway.  https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/

Comment: Heads up on the last paragraph: not all is rosy even in more modern libraries. `Moment().month()` and date-fn's `getMonth()` are both still 0-based. Luxon and js-joda's month functions appear to be 1-based.

Comment: @YassirKhaldi — Why would you blame a guy who did a thing for doing that thing?  I mean, even if it was the right decision, or the right decision at the time, it's still that person's fault that it is was done the way that it was.

Comment: Interestingly, a quirk that was not copied from Java's `Date` is representing the year as "year minus 1900". Yes, we live in the year 123 right now.

Answer (score 35):

Everything but the day of the month is 0 based, [see here for a full list including ranges](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) :)

It's actually the 1 based days that are the oddballs here...oddly enough.  Why was this was done? I don't know...but probably happened the same meeting they got plastered and decided semicolons were optional.

Comment: The "ones-based" days thing is probably because no one in their right mind would ever create an array of string names for days (e.g., `{ "first", "second", "third", ..., "twenty-seventh", ... }`) and try to index it by `tm_mday`. Then again, maybe they just saw the absolute utility in making _off by one_ errors a regular occurrence.

Comment: They why years are not 0 based?

Comment: @Vedmant there are (for practical purposes) an infinite number of years in both the negative and positive directions. The year isn't really "based" at all because it's not a fixed set of values.

Comment: Imagine the day of the month being zero-based:
index 0 => day 1;
indez 1 => day 2;
...

What could possibly go wrong? XD

Answer (score 24):

In 2023 the real question is:

> If `Date` was broken from JS day one, why after 28 years (27 if you count from zero) it's still here?

JS has a lot of bad parts/quirks and the worst thing is that some of them haven't been fixed in *decades* (fun fact: we're talking about `Date` *dates*).

But we're lucky, it looks like the end of `Date` is near.

### Spoiler

```
new Temporal.PlainDate(2020, 11, 26); // => 2020-11-26
```

---

### Temporal (proposal)

From the proposal introduction:

> `Date` has been a long-standing pain point in ECMAScript. This is a proposal for `Temporal`, a global `Object` that acts as a top-level namespace (like `Math`), that brings a modern date/time API to the ECMAScript language.

It's based, as reported in docs, "on common use cases we examined" and has a multiple types for different kinds of data:

- `Plain` types do not have a timezone
- `ZonedDateTime` types have a timezone
- most types have a calendar
- many useful types: `Absolute`, `DateTime`, `Date`, `Time`, `TimeZone`, ...

This is a schema that outline various `Temporal` types and their relationships
[image: JS Temporal proposal Types]

You can read more about them in the available [documentation](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) and in the nice [cookbook](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/cookbook.html). Or explore current [issues](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal/issues) for open ones.

### When Temporal will be available

Since [March '21](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal/commit/e69c905837297a1a5e6b72c257b3c19e33cd5661#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5R7) it's in **Stage 3/Draft** (see [TC39 stages reference](https://tc39.es/process-document/)). See TC39 [March '21 slides](https://ptomato.github.io/temporal-slides-in-progress/).

Now it can be included in TypeScript soon, since their [policy](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) is:

> When new features have reached stage 3, then they are ready for inclusion in TypeScript.

Probably for Node and major browsers we'll need to wait more.

### Start experimenting today

In the meanwhile you can experiment with it using the [Temporal polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal/tree/main/polyfill).

```
npm install --save proposal-temporal

// temporal-test.js
const { Temporal } = require('proposal-temporal');

// or as an ES module
// import { Temporal } from 'proposal-temporal/lib/index.mjs';

// 11 means November now!
const date = new Temporal.PlainDate(2020, 11, 26); // => 2020-11-26

const sameDate = Temporal.PlainDate.from(
                {year: 2020, month: 11, day: 26}); // => 2020-11-26
```

Answer (score 8):

I know it's not really an answer to the original question, but I just wanted to show you my preferred solution to this problem, which I never seem to memorize as it pops up from time to time.

The small function zerofill does the trick filling the zeroes where needed, and the month is just `+1` added:

```js
function zerofill(i) {
    return (i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i;
}

function getDateString() {
    const date = new Date();
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = zerofill(date.getMonth()+1);
    const day = zerofill(date.getDate());
    return year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
}
```

But yes, Date has a pretty unintuitive API, I was laughing when I read Brendan Eich's Twitter.

Answer (score 5):

There are always 12 months in a year, so early C implementations might have used a static fixed-width array with indexes 0..11.

Comment: The Java Date/Calendar implementation maintains support for an extra month for some calendars. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecimber

Answer (score 4):

Its like this in java too.. **Probably** to convert int to string (0 - jan,, 1-feb), they coded this way.. because they might have an array of string (indexed from 0) of month names and these month numbers if they start from 0, it'll be lot easier to map to the month strings..

Answer (score 2):

They might've considered months to be an enumeration (first index being 0) and days not since they don't have a name associated with them.

Or rather, they thought the number of the day was the actual representation of the day (the same way months are represented as numbers in a date like 12/31), as if you could make a enumeration with numbers as the variables, but actually 0-based.

So actually, for the months, perhaps they thought the proper enumeration representation would be to use the month's name, instead of numbers, and they would've done the same if days had a name representation. Imagine if we'd say January Five, January Sixth, instead of January 5, January 6, etc., then perhaps they'd have made a 0-based enumeration for days too...

Perhaps subconsciously they thought about an enumeration for months as {January, February, ...} and for days as {One, Two, Three, ...}, except for days you access the day as a number rather than the name, like 1 for One, etc., so impossible to start at 0...

Comment: You should dual-class to Psychologist. It's still a mistake they made, but at least we now understand why they made it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a flaw, but it's also very handy when you want to represent the months or day of the week as a string you can just create an array like ['jan,'feb' ...etc][new Date().getMonth()] in stead of ['','jan',feb ...etc][new Date().getMonth()] or ['jan','feb' ...etc][new Date().getMonth()-1]

days of the month are normaly not named so you won't be making arrays with names for those. In this case 1-31 is easier to handle, so you want have to subtract 1 every time...

Comment: not really. You could easily just subtract one. It creates more problems than it solves because now when you do math with dates, you have to do specific manipulation on the month rather often.

Answer (score -1):

the simple solution **new Date(year,month,day)** : -

```
let year = 2022
let month = 4
let day = 25
//use 
new Date(year,month-1,day)
```

Comment: I think it's generally understood from the question that one has to do this. I think the question is more about *why* you have to, to which the answer is "Because JS Date was based on Java's and the creator didn't have time to think about all the negative repercussions that this would have."