# why does javascript getMonth count from 0 and getDate count from 1?

Tags: javascript, date

This question is purely to satisfy my curiosity.

In the JavaScript Date object, when you call `getMonth()` it returns the month but it counts from 0.

```
0 = January
1 = February 
...
```

But when you call `getDate()` it starts counting from 1

```
1 = 1
2 = 2
...
```

Why the inconsistency?

Comment: but getDate() returns day of month, not month...

Comment: then again getDay() Returns the day of the week (from 0-6) ...

Comment: I'd guess because a day of the month is actually a *value*, where the month is more of an enumerable type (eg, you might want to map it to an array of month names).  But it could also just be that dates in JavaScript are a gigantic mess and can never be changed.

Comment: Good question. But I don't think that there is a answer to this that makes sense, that's just how things are.

Comment: This is most confusing in the constructor new Date(2017, 1, 1), which is the 1st of February 2017.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552483/why-does-the-month-argument-range-from-0-to-11-in-javascripts-date-constructor

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I assume it's because it would be easier to reference in an array of names, i.e.

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
         "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var d = new Date();

var namedMonth = months[d.getMonth()];
```

If `getMonth()` returned `1-12`, then programmers would have to do `d.getMonth()-1` everytime they wanted a fancy named month.

Days of the month don't have specific "names" per se. The `getDate()` returns `1-(28-31)`. We usually just refer to them by their number.

The same concept as `getMonth()` applies for `getDay()` also, which returns `0-6` based on the day of the week

```
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

var namedDay = days[d.getDay()];
```

All this returns something like:

```
console.log("Month: month[" + d.getMonth() + "]: " + namedMonth); 
//Month: month[3]:  April
console.log("Day: days[" + d.getDay() + "]: " + namedDay); 
// Day: days[4] : Thursday
```

Comment: How does this explain why `.getDate()` starts at `1`?

Comment: He's asking about `.getDate()` and not about `.getDay()`

Comment: javascript sucks if it was really made that way by this reason. For me it would be easier to do: var months=['', 'Jan', ...]; than remember that getMonth can return 0.

Comment: @Stanislav a lot of languages are like that...JavaScript isn't the first

Comment: What's this about Japanese…? :)

Comment: They're still using the same numbers in writing though, which is why that comment is a bit odd… :)

Comment: *If `getMonth()` returned 1-12, then programmers would have to do `d.getMonth()-1` everytime they wanted a fancy named month.*
--- Doesn't seem logical. Because if programmers want to have the month number, then they have to do `d.getMonth()+1`

Answer (score 7):

Coming a bit late to this, but the correct answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41992352/134120

They (the creators of JavaScript) copied the functionality from the corresponding class in Java (which in turn seems to have been copied from C). And so we're propagating the mistakes of the past ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say it's inconsistency - you need to ask the creator of specification of language. According to this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Language_Resources) `JavaScript` is based on `ECMAScript` (EDIT: see @MichaelGeary comment).

And when you read from page 165 [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), you will see that all is working exactly as it's designed.

For you it can be inconsistency. For me it's rather a feature - 0-based values let you access `Array` straight away without doing calculations (see @Christopher's answer). In case of day of month you can't really access any `Array`. It will be weird to have `Array` of names of days of the month... like this:

```
var namesOfDays = [
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", // and again at least 4 times ...
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"
]
```

Comment: You're right that this behavior is "as designed", but you have your history wrong. JavaScript is not based on ECMAScript, it's the other way around: [JavaScript was developed in 1995 and submitted to Ecma for standardization the next year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#History). The ECMAScript standard was written to describe JavaScript as it actually existed. The reason the standard says what it says is that's how JavaScript already worked.

Answer (score 0):

[Link1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> Date.prototype.getDate()
>       Returns the day of the month (1-31) for the specified date according to local time.

[Link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/date-object-javascript)

> A Date object contains a number representing a particular instant in
>   time to within a millisecond
>   For example, if you specify 150 seconds, JavaScript redefines that number as two minutes and 30 seconds.

When you implement methods in Javascript to find the difference between two times specified in miliseconds, you would need to return a `date` which needs to be `greater than 0` for obvious reasons.

```
var startTime = new Date('1/1/1990');  
var startMsec = startTime.getMilliseconds();  
startTime.setTime(5000000);  
var elapsed = (startTime.getTime() - startMsec) / 1000;   
document.write(elapsed);  

// Output: 5000
```

---

As explained by "SomeShinyObject" that

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
         "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
```

helps in referencing them through array index.

Hence `getDay`, `getHours`, `getMonths` starts from 0.

Comment: I don't understand what your talk about dates represented as a number of milliseconds or finding the difference between two dates has to do with this question.