# Date.getDay() returns wrong day of the week

Tags: javascript, date

My server sends current server time, and I need to handle them with JS.

```
var currentDate = new Date(someYear, someMonth, someDay, 12);
console.log(currentDate.getDate()+'.'
            +currentDate.getMonth()+'.'
            +currentDate.getFullYear()
        ); //8.4.2016 - this is right, today is 8th April of 2016
console.log(currentDate.getDay()); // 0. But today is Friday, not Monday!
```

Why currentDay.getDay() returns wrong number?

Comment: @Hacketo sorry, this was a typo.

Comment: `getMonth` is 0 index based so 4 is `May`

Comment: @Hacketo Why on Earth someone made months to start from '0'? 

Thank you for the solution.

Comment: With a 0 index based value you can easily use an array see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799514/why-does-javascript-getmonth-count-from-0-and-getdate-count-from-1

Comment: Month 4 = May. Months start counting from 0. That makes it Sunday, which is the first day of the week (day 0)