# why getDay() in javascript return +1 day of a week?

Tags: javascript, date

Today is 07 May 2016, Saturday
But when I implement a js practice, the getDay() always return the correct number plus one. So I did this test.

[image]

Today is Saturday, so I expect to return 5 rather than 6.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Search documentation first and then post actual code instead of pictures of code

Comment: PS: date.getMonth() will return zero-based months - Jan is 0

Comment: I think adding to the confusion is the fact the _date_ is the 7th.  The 6 is unrelated to that.  You'll get 6 next weekend on Saturday, when the date is the 14th too.

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you for your hint and guide. I will learn that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The getDay() method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

So if Sunday is 0 then you get these values for the other days:

1. Monday
2. Tuesday
3. Wednesday
4. Thursday
5. Friday
6. Saturday

Comment: Thank you so much. I was in china, Monday is the begin of a week but now I am in Australia, Sunday should be the begin. I have understood it now.

Comment: I was recently stuck in the rabbit hole while working with translators on a project I wrote https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/global_developer/2011/06/03/what-is-the-first-day-of-the-week-really/

Comment: @user3210050: `getDay` will always return `0` for Sunday, no matter where you are.

Comment: @Felix Kling Yes, I did not realise it before.Monday is the first day in my mind before, so I should read the documentation clearly at first. Sorry for my weakness.

Comment: Solving this bug now would make a whole lot of code non-backward-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The day of the week:

```
var d = new Date(2016, 5, 20); // June 20, 2016
d.getDay();
```

Starting the count from 0 (Sunday), 1 means Monday and etc...

@Mike C:

- **0** Sunday
- **1** Monday
- **2** Tuesday
- **3** Wednesday
- **4** Thursday
- **5** Friday
- **6** Saturday

You will have the same situation with month too. The value returned by getMonth() is an integer between 0 and 11. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

- **0** January
- **1** February
- **2** March
- **3** April
- **4** May
- **5** June
- **6** July
- **7** August
- **8** September
- **9** October
- **10** November
- **11** December

`var d = new Date(2016, 5, 20); // June 20, 2016`

`d.getMonth(); // 5`

**Why?**

As assumed [@ChristopherW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15799570/603774) this can help to reference in an array of names.

```
var 
  months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
  days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

var d = new Date(2016, 5, 20); // June 20, 2016

months[d.getMonth()]; // "June"
days[d.getDay()]; // "Monday"
```

It is very convenient for developers. But there is another reason for zero-indexing. The syntax of JavaScript is actually derived from C. Lets analize C's [localtime](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_localtime.htm) function.

> The C library function struct tm *localtime(const time_t *timer) uses
>   the time pointed by timer to fill a tm structure with the values that
>   represent the corresponding local time. The value of timer is broken
>   up into the structure tm and expressed in the local time zone.
>
> `struct tm *localtime(const time_t *timer)`
>
> This function returns a pointer to a tm structure with the time
>   information filled in. Following is the tm structure information:
>
> ```
> struct tm {
>    int tm_sec;         /* seconds,  range 0 to 59          */
>    int tm_min;         /* minutes, range 0 to 59           */
>    int tm_hour;        /* hours, range 0 to 23             */
>    int tm_mday;        /* day of the month, range 1 to 31  */
>    int tm_mon;         /* month, range 0 to 11             */
>    int tm_year;        /* The number of years since 1900   */
>    int tm_wday;        /* day of the week, range 0 to 6    */
>    int tm_yday;        /* day in the year, range 0 to 365  */
>    int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time             */ 
> };
> ```

As you see month starts from 0 to 11, day of the week from 0 to 6.

Comment: Javascript is more based on Java than C (there are many languages with C–like syntax), its Date object is almost a copy from Java.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add 6 and use modulus operator.

```
var d = new Date(2016, 5, 20);

var weekday = (d.getDay() + 6) % 7;
```