# Angular date issue

Tags: javascript, angular

[image: Date is april 1 2000 but getMonth says it is 3 (march)]

I have an object with a date property. I set the date to 01 April 2000 and can see in the debugger that it is set properly to the same date. However when I do a getMonth() on the same date object it returns month as 3 ( March ) . Why is this happening. Does it have anything to do with UTC or Localization both of which i am not using ?

Comment: Months are zero-based in JavaScript. January is `0`, April is `3`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why does javascript getMonth count from 0 and getDate count from 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799514/why-does-javascript-getmonth-count-from-0-and-getdate-count-from-1)

Comment: `let mm=this.candidateInfo.dateOfBirth.getMonth();`
`mm=mm+1`;

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Folks who downvoted, this was a genuine question. I was not aware that in JS months are 0 based and there was no way I would have hit the other question without this knowledge.

Comment: Downvotes are also likely because you have made debugging hard by posting code as an image. Post code as code, we can then copy and paste as required.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Jon P. I was trying to show the debug tip :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need +1 for getMonth function
`var month = date.getMonth() + 1`

Answer (score 0):

this is normal behavior. Months starts with Zero(i.e january is 0). thats why its giving 3 for april. use adding 1 with month to get exact month's digit value.

i guess, to help indexing javascript starts month with zero.
 suppose an array of months in string form then we dont have to worry to fetch correct month from string.