# DataTime Regular expression yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm and dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm and not Check For 30 and february

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match

```
yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm
```

and another one match

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
```

and also check to for 30 and  31 and. using JavaScript

Match for example

```
2000/02/28 11:55

28/02/2000 11:55
```

not match for example

```
2000/02/31 11:55

31/02/2000 11:55
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  What about enforcing the correct number of days for _every_ month?

Comment: i try http://regexlib.com/UserPatterns.aspx?authorId=1cf694cb-67e7-47c8-9efe-22b809684d48

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I'll help with the regex, if that's something you want to understand:

If you want to match yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm then use

```
\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}
```

[See it working here](https://regex101.com/r/6adb1u/1)

To explain:

```
\d{4} four digits (year) yy
\/ escape slash
\d{2} two digits (month) MM
\/ escape slash
\d{2} two digits (date) dd
\s single space character
\d{2} two digits (hour) hh
: colon (string literal)
\d{2} two digits (minutes) mm
```

For your other version just swap over the 4 and 2

```
\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}
```

You can then check the date for valid numbers - but as Tim Biegeleisen says, you should check for all months.

Comment: i want to not match 2000/02/31 11:55

Comment: That's not gonna happen in a regular expression. You first need to validate a string is in time format you want and **then** you can determine if it's a valid date or not. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188420/javascript-date-validation-not-validation-february-31), it may help you