# Javascript - Don't auto adjust invalid dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I'm trying to prevent Javascript from automatically adjusting an invalid date.

**For example:**
`2/31/2000` becomes `3/2/2000`

```
var x = new Date("02/31/2000");
var maxDate = new Date("03/01/2020");

if(x > maxDate){
    //date is invalid
} else {
    //date is valid
}
//March 2st, 2020 is logged to the console
console.log(x);
```

**What I need**: is a solution (in Javascript or Jquery) that does not allow an invalid date like that, instead of auto adjust the month as seen above.

**Solution exists here!**

Stackoverflow just notified me that there's an answer to this already.

[javascript date validation not validation February 31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188420/javascript-date-validation-not-validation-february-31)

Not sure what to do with this question... close it?  Delete it?  Can some mods take the appropriate action please?  And thanks!

Comment: You'll have to parse the date strings yourself, because that's a basic (and useful) feature of the JavaScript Date facility.

Comment: Or of course you could format the resulting date similarly to the input format and compare for equality. In other words, if you make a Date from a source string, then format it to another string, and they're not the same, then the "adjustment" must have occurred.

Comment: @Pointy—it's not a specified feature. Parsing of unsupported string formats is implementation dependent. For `new Date("02/31/2000")`, some may return an invalid date (or not…). :-)

Comment: @RobG well yes that's true of course. My point was that if the runtime is willing to parse the date, it'll also "fix" it (in all cases I know of). I guess egregious bogus dates might get rejected sometimes, like 3-digit month numbers or something.

Comment: @Pointy—given `new Date('2020-02-31')`, Safari and Firefox return an invalid date, Chrome returns 2 Mar 2020. :-(