# Javascript Date -> numeric vs string

Tags: javascript, date

```
    var date1 = new Date('1900-01-01');
    console.log(date1);
```

Yields:
"Mon Jan 01 1900 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)"

```
    var date2 = new Date(1900,1,1);
    console.log(date2);
```

Yields:
"Thu Feb 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)"

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crosstalk/t1p137vz/1/)

But I don't understand why!

Answer (score 1):

You can see the month difference since when you pass individual components (year, month, day, etc) to the `Date` object constructor, you have to consider that month parameter should start with `0`:

```
console.log( new Date('1900-01-01').getMonth() );  // 0
```

Other than Jan/Feb there shouldn't be any differences in dates.

**MDN:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It shouldn't display any hour difference, just month difference.

Comment: Agreed. It shouldn't. But that's what's in the question... Typo maybe?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I tend to think that this is a typo.

Comment: @crosstalk Fiddle will display exactly what *your* browser will display. In my case the time is the same: https://i.gyazo.com/d949455b043ffc7f0929d278aeb618ef.png.

Comment: Should've been more clear - It's only the jan/feb thing that confuses me - but you're saying that is supposed to be like that?

Comment: Yeah, Jan/Feb thing is supposed to be like that because of month numbering in JavaScript. However, I don't know why you have different time. It may be something related to your locale, although not sure.

Comment: Ah, ok - so months starts on 0 and days on 1? But why? :-) Agree with the time explanation though.

Comment: @crosstalk Yes, months start with 0. Here is one brief discussion about that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2552483/1249581 `:)`

Comment: @VisioN: Haha! Thanks for the link :-)