# Date function return incorrect value in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

```
//var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
new Date(2017,01,31);
```

The result is: **Fri Mar 03 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100**

Without parameters is correct:

```
new Date()
```

The result is: **Wed Feb 01 2017 23:10:22 GMT+0100**

Why?

Comment: oooooowww, the month started in 0

Comment: See also: [WHY](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41992352/634824)

Answer (score 1):

new Date(2017,01,31);

Months are 0 indexed based

So here it is feb 2017 and 31st date ,as february does not have 31 it is moving march and adding up the rest of dates. ie., feb 28+3(days) i.e., march 3rd

hope it helps