# Initialize JS date object from HTML date picker: incorrect date returned

Tags: javascript, html, date, timezone, locale

How do you correctly intitialize a timezone-independent date (or I guess a date that is fixed to a single timezone across the html side and the JS side) from a html datepicker?

I have the following simple code, which is producing incorrect dates:

```js
function printDate(){
 let d = new Date(document.getElementById("date").value)
 alert(d)
}

document.getElementById("printDate").addEventListener("click", e => printDate())
```

```html
<html>
<body>
Print Date: <br><input type="date" id="date"> <button id="printDate">Add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

But at least on my computer, currently sitting in U.S. mountain time, it produces incorrect dates.  I give it today's date (March 9, 2019), and it alerts yesterday's date in the following format: `Fri Mar 08 2019 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)`. How do I make it not do that?

I really just want it to assume that all input and all output are in GMT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `<input type="date" />` element, the selected date is displayed in the locale format, but the `value` property is always returned in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, as described in [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value).

In other words, when you choose March 9, 2019, you may see `03/09/2019` from the US or `09/03/2019` in other parts of the world, but `value` is `2019-03-09` regardless of any time zone or localization settings.  This is a good thing, as it allows you to work with the selected date in a standard ISO 8601 format, without trying to apply a time.

However, when you parse a date string in that format with the `Date` object's constructor (or with `Date.parse`), you run up against a known issue: The date is not treated as local time, but as UTC.  This is the *opposite* of ISO 8601.

This is described [in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters):

> **Note:** parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and `Date.parse`, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

It's also [in the ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-date-time-string-format) (emphasis mine):

> ... When the time zone offset is absent, **date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time** and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time.

There was [a debate about this in 2015](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/87), but ultimately it was decided that maintaining compatibility with existing behaviors was more important than being ISO 8601 compliant.

Going back to your question, the best thing to do would be to *not* parse it into a `Date` object if you don't need one.  In other words:

```js
function printDate(){
    const d = document.getElementById("date").value;
    alert(d);
}
```

If you really need a `Date` object, then the easiest option is to parse the value yourself:

```js
function printDate(){
    const parts = document.getElementById("date").value.split('-');
    const d = new Date(+parts[0], parts[1]-1, +parts[2], 12);
    alert(d);
}
```

Note the `,12` at the end sets the time to noon instead of midnight.  This is optional, but it avoids situations of getting the wrong day when midnight doesn't exist in the local time zone where DST transitions at midnight (Brazil, Cuba, etc.).

Then there's your last comment:

> I really just want it to assume that all input and all output are in GMT.

That's a bit different than what you showed.  If really that's what you want, then you can construct the `Date` object as you previously did, and use `.toISOString()`, `.toGMTString()`, or `.toLocaleString(undefined, {timeZone: 'UTC'})`

```js
function printDate(){
    const d = new Date(document.getElementById("date").value); // will treat input as UTC

    // will output as UTC in ISO 8601 format
    alert(d.toISOString());

    // will output as UTC in an implementation dependent format
    alert(d.toGMTString());

    // will output as UTC in a locale specific format
    alert(d.toLocaleString(undefined, {timeZone: 'UTC'}));
}
```

Comment: Omg.  I didn't quite undestand this answer, so I did some experiments, and this behavior happens only with this SPECIFIC FORMAT of dates parsed as strings.  So `let d = new Date("03/09/2019");alert(d)` produces correct timezone-independent output, but "2019-03-09" does not.  Thank you, but also, GARGH JAVASCRIPT WHY??!!

Comment: Well, I guess correct not in the sense of timezone independent, but in the sense of, input is the same time zone as output... which seems like a pretty bare minimum.  Sigh.

Comment: Not really.  One can't really alert or log a `Date` object directly, only some string representation.  When you do, the implementation is not defined by spec.  Some will implicitly call `toString` (which gives local time), but some implentations will implicitly call `toISOString` (which gives UTC).

Comment: Also, I'd avoid passing a local specific format like `"03/09/2019"`, as it will be interpreted differently depending on the locale.  March 9th vs September 3rd.  Also, again the spec doesn't provided any requirement for this format, so implementations could vary.

Comment: As to "why" - I feel your pain.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41992352/634824) for some idea of where it started from.

Comment: Heh.  Yeah.  I wish there was a way to opt into naive one-country-behavior, for use cases like mine. I'm writing a tiny little scheduling thing mostly for local use by a handful of people within a few miles of one another. This was a "banged it out in another language and realized that it won't be used by anyone if they have to install an executable oh god fine I'll rewrite it in JavaScript and put it on the front end AAAH THE PAIN!!!" kind of a situation. :-)