# How to block off a date in Kendo DatePicker

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

Is there a way to block off a date with the Kendo DatePicker? So if they click open the calendar, and they want to select the 10th of December, I can have that date either disabled or removed ( preferrably disabled ). I don't see any documentation on how to do this.

```
<div id="datePicker"></div>

$('#datePicker').kendoDatePicker({
   // I need it dynamically done, I don't want to hard code the date. 
   // So if the user clicks it, a request will be handled to send back any dates that are previously taken.
});
```

Comment: First google hit https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/disable-dates :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the 10th Dec you can do it like this:

```
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    value: new Date(2019,11,5),
    disableDates: [new Date(2019,11,10)]
});
```

disableDates can be an array or a function. You can use dates or weekday names. please check the documentation in my comment to know more. Please notice that 11 is month 12. [Why does the month argument range from 0 to 11 in JavaScript's Date constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552483/why-does-the-month-argument-range-from-0-to-11-in-javascripts-date-constructor)

If you would like to use a function here is how:

```
disableDates: function (date) {
    var dates = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").options.dates;
                if (your condition) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```