# Why are my dates aren't working in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to initialize a Date object by doing:

```js
let date = new Date(2020, 12, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

then when I do

```js
date.getMonth()
```

I get `0`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the month argument range from 0 to 11 in JavaScript's Date constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552483/why-does-the-month-argument-range-from-0-to-11-in-javascripts-date-constructor)

Comment: Months are in range (0...11) % 12 -> so You actually provided 0 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Months are zero-indexed, so the month you want to initialize it with is actually 11. It doesn't know what to do with 12, that would be month number 13.

Answer (score 1):

`date.getMonth()` returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year) according to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth).

Answer (score 0):

The month argument of `Date` is zero based - 0 represents January and 11 represents December. Assuming you meant to create an object for the fifth of December 2020, you should use 11, not 12:

```js
let date = new Date(2020, 11, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0);
// Here ------------------^
```