# Why is Month Returning Last Month?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm simply trying to get the current month.  As of today when I post this, it's August 3rd... so why is the month logging as 7 instead of 8?

If I log date, it says "Aug 3rd".  But when I log month, it says 7.

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(date) // logs "Tues Aug 3rd....
const year = date.getFullYear();
let month = date.getMonth();
console.log(month); // logs 7 <---- why?
```

Comment: [JS Months start at 0](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+month+wrong+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552483/why-does-the-month-argument-range-from-0-to-11-in-javascripts-date-constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript month begins at 0 not 1

Comment: Ah... thanks.  I didn't realize dates counted that way.

Comment: [Massive dupe...](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+month+wrong+site%3Astackoverflow.com)