# Incorrect date returned

Tags: javascript

Tell. Why is the wrong date returned to me when MANUALly entering the date in new Date()?
If you choose through the calendar, then everything works

```
const newDate = new Date(2022,10,10)
```

Expected to return October 10, but is returning 2022-11-09

Comment: the month number is zero based (0-11)

Comment: here's one of the many qa addressing this topic here on SO [Why does the month argument range from 0 to 11 in JavaScript's Date constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552483/why-does-the-month-argument-range-from-0-to-11-in-javascripts-date-constructor)

Comment: @DiegoD Strange. I did -1 from the month and it flattened out, but my date is not current either. If you make +1 to the date, then the date breaks. I enter 10/10/2022, and I get 2023-01-08

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what's going on when you say `If you make +1 to the date, then the date breaks` but I suspect it's a different question. The [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) just expects those three values to be the arguments `year, monthIndex, day` where `monthIndex` starts from zero. Be sure to use numbers (not strings) when dealing with those arguments especially if you are doing math operations like `+ 1`

Answer (score 4):

The months start with 0, unlike the rest. The month of October will be index 9.

```js
const date = new Date(2022,9,10)
```

[image: result]

```
0  -> Jan
1  -> Feb
2  -> Mar
3  -> Apr
4  -> May
5  -> Jun
6  -> Jul
7  -> Aug
8  -> Sep
9  -> Oct
10 -> Nov
11 -> Dec
```

Hopefully it will fit !