# Why are months off by one with Java SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, date, formatting

I am using SimpleDateFormat to display a Calendar like this :

```
public String getDate()
{
    String DATE_FORMAT = "EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    System.err.println(date.getTime().getMonth());
    return sdf.format(date.getTime());
}
```

The shell returns `6` and the display : `mardi, 06/07/2010 12:44:52`

It can't be possible ? Why ?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar Good question....

Comment: Where did the variable `date` come from in your code?  Is it just a class variable initialized to the current time and date?

Comment: From `date.set()` when `Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance()` and I didn't realized that month should be between 0 and 11.

Comment: What is the problem? You ran it on June 7, 2010, and the output says 06/07/2010. That is correct.

Comment: No because the `DATE_FORMAT` is not `MM/dd/yyyy` but `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [Java API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getMonth()):

> public int getMonth()
>
> Returns a number representing the month that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object. The value returned is between 0 and 11, with the value 0 representing January.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, months in class `Date` and class `Calendar` are zero-based. (In my opinion, this was a huge design mistake in those classes, and it's just one of the many design mistakes in Java's date and time API).

Note that class `Calendar` has constants to represent the months: `Calendar.JANUARY`, `Calendar.FEBRUARY` etc. Use those instead of the raw numbers.

An often mentioned, much better date and time API for Java is [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). Note that there is a proposal to add a new date and time API to the next version of Java that will be based on Joda Time.

Comment: Java inherited that design mistake from POSIX, I believe. Originally intended to allow the month value to be used as an index into an array of month names.

Answer (score 1):

the getMonth method in Date is 0 indexed.  from the JavaDoc:

> Returns a number representing the month that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object. The value returned is between 0 and 11, with the value 0 representing January.

Answer (score 1):

month index starts from 0 just like array index

Answer (score 0):

that's your locale set to france DD/MM/YY so it is tuesday, July, 2010.
the 6th month is july if it starts at 0.