# Parsing zero-based month strings in java

Tags: java, parsing, date

I am trying to parse a String that looks like:

```
2015, 2, 31, 17, 0, 1
```

so i figured I'll use

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy, MM, dd, hh, mm, ss")
```

but it assumed the months are 1-based. In this case the month (2) is March. How can i tell SimpleDateFormat or any other class to parse with zero-based months?

Comment: is there a reason you cannot just add one to the month immediately before formatting it with the date format? That would seem like it would solve the problem.

Comment: There are no placeholders for 0-based month in SimpleDateFormat, so you need to change month explicitly or create a date using Calendar.

Comment: @DavisBroda: How would you expect that to work with the example given, which would be parsed as "February 31st" (and thus either adjusted or failing to parse).

Comment: @DavisBroda I am doing comparisons in java before sending the strings along to a javascript environment (which uses zero-based months), that's why I can't change the strings.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thinking it through in more detail, my vague idea would not work. It was based on a misunderstanding of what the question was asking. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
String[] yourString = "2015, 2, 31, 17, 0, 1".split(",");

Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.valueOf(yourString[0]));
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.valueOf(yourString[1]));
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.valueOf(yourString[2]));
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(yourString[3]));
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(yourString[4]));
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.valueOf(yourString[5]));
```

Comment: Which overload of `set` is that using? (You want `Integer.parseInt` calls there...)

Comment: Yeah I figured I could "parse" the string manually, but I had hoped there would be a better way =).

Answer (score 0):

One solution i can see increase one month  with

```
Date newDate = DateUtils.addMonths(new Date(), 1);
```

With calendar

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

By default months are 0 based index. see

[Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

[Why are months off by one with Java SimpleDateFormat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992381/why-are-months-off-by-one-with-java-simpledateformat)