# java calendar wrong day

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want to check if the date is weekend (lets say 28 august 2016), but for some arkane reason it returns the wrong day
The code is as follows

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy,mm,dd");
depDate = format.parse(departure_date);
Calendar calDeparture = Calendar.getInstance();
calDeparture.setTime(depDate);
if (calDeparture.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY && calArrival.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        Log.d("true", "WEEKEND");
    }else {
        Log.d("FALSE", "NOT WEEKEND");
    }
```

for some strange reason when i do Log.d("DAY OF WEEk:", Integer.toString(calDeparture.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))); on the 28 of august it returns 4

Comment: "mm" means minutes, not months... if you look at the result of the parse, you'll see what's going on. It's also very odd to use commas in a date format.

Comment: i get the same result. nothing changes. the 28 of august prints out 4th day of week

Comment: In that case, you need to provide a [mcve] showing the issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet I  managed to get it work. the problem was this line of code: departureDateTrue = Integer.toString(year)+","+Integer.toString(month)+","+Integer.toString(day); i changed it departureDateTrue = Integer.toString(year)+","+Integer.toString(month+1)+","+Integer.toString(day);

Comment: When the problem is in code that isn't in the question, it's really hard for us to help you. Please learn from this experience: a question with a [mcve] is much better than an incomplete one like this. Also note that you'd be better off *not* formatting the date like that to start with, but instead populating a `Calendar` (or better, a Java 8 time value) and formatting that. As it is, your value won't match the specified format when the day number or month number is less than 10...

Comment: When this was your problem, then this is a suitable dupe: [Why are months off by one with Java SimpleDateFormat?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2992381)

Answer (score 1):

Your format is wrong. Month must be uppercase MM

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy,MM,dd");
```

lowercase mm is Minute.

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy,MM,dd");
    Date depDate = format.parse("2016,8,28");
    Calendar calDeparture = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(depDate);
    calDeparture.setTime(depDate);
    System.out.println(calDeparture.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

Output is:

```
Sun Aug 28 00:00:00 CEST 2016
1
```

Comment: i get the same result. nothing changes. the 28 of august prints out 4th day of week

Comment: @denis for me it works fine and returns 1. See my excample.

Comment: I  managed to get it work. the problem was this line of code: departureDateTrue = Integer.toString(year)+","+Integer.toString(month)+","+Integer.toString(day); i changed it departureDateTrue = Integer.toString(year)+","+Integer.toString(month+1)+","+Integer.toString(day);

Comment: @denis that is code you not Show in your question

Comment: I know, but i thought it wasn't important. Actually i have a question as .get(Calendar.MONTH); returns 7 (for august) why i needed to change it to 8 for the code to work

Comment: @denis it is Zero based