# Java Calendar date manipulation issue

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

I am try to get the current date/time in in following format,

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"); 
// should display something similar to  2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2009, 2, 4, 10, 22, 44);
format.format( calendar.getTime() );
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

But it display as Wed Mar 04 10:22:44 IST 2009.

The second question is I want to see the milliseconds value of the set time.

```
System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

But it always return the current times milliseconds value and not the time I set earlier.

What is I am missing here?

Comment: Months start with 0, so 2 is March. Legacy API be damned!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar

Answer (score 2):

The `SimpleDateFormat#format(Object)` method returns a formatted `String`, it does not affect how the `Calendar#getTime()` method returns. To that end you should do a:

```
System.out.println(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem that I see is that `format.format(calendar.getTime());` returns a String and doesn't actually change the formatting of the Calendar. You are going to want to replace the last two lines with `System.out.println(format.format(calendar.getTime()));` to actually print out the date using the format you specify (assuming your SimpleDateFormat is valid, but it looks OK at a quick glance).

Not sure about the second problem you are having, unfortunately, but I have a place for you to start. I'm not a fan of the wording of the Javadocs for `getTime()` and `getTimeInMillis()`. The `getTime()` method returns "a `Date` object representing this `Calendar`'s time value" while `getTimeInMillis()` returns "the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch". To me, the difference in wording implies that `getTimeInMillis()` doesn't use the date specified by the Calendar object, even though it is an instance method. Try `System.out.println(calendar.getTime().getTime());` in order to call the `getTime()` method on the `Date` representation of the Calendar, which is document to return the time in milliseconds between 1 January 1970 and the date represented by the Date object.

Comment: Thanks Thomas..still even i use calendar.getTime().getTime() it returns diferent long values when ever i run the code...shouldnt it only display a static value representing the date i set ealier

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, you should call `Calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECONDS)` to retrieve the milliseconds field of a calendar object.

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants...my understanding is that this returns the number of milliseconds in the given time. "Field number for get and set indicating the millisecond within the second. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the MILLISECOND is 250."

Comment: @Thomas Owens - my understanding of the question is that this is exactly what he is asking for.

Comment: Perhaps. But the getTimeInMillis() method does get time in milliseconds based on the epoch, not the millisecond value of the Calendar object.