# JavaScript setDate returning wrong dates

Tags: javascript, date

I'm getting a date from a string, parsing it to get the day, month and year constituants and use these to instance a Date object.

What I am trying to achieve is to increment the date by one day.
It all works fine except that the setDate method insists on returning me invalid dates sometimes...

For example, if I add 1 day to the 28th February 2011, it will return me 29th February 2011... a date which actually doesn't exist.

Is that a bug/limitation of the JavaScript's native Date/Time API, or am I just doing something wrong? I find it hard to believe that it behaves that way without checking the validity of the date.

```js
var myDate = new Date(2011, 2, 28);
console.log(myDate.toString());

myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
console.log(myDate.toString()); // 29 February 2011 !
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not in February - month #2 is MARCH

JS months are 0 based

```
 var myDate = new Date(2011, 1, 28); // 28th of Feb
 alert(myDate);
 myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
 alert(myDate); // 1st of March 2011 !
```

PS: Where you MAY have some issues are across the daylight savings time if you are creating dates using `var d = new Date()` and don't normalise on hours by doing `d.setHours(0,0,0,0)` afterwards

Comment: I see now, thanks a lot. I'm coming from a .Net background and the DateTime object does not behave that way in there... I was suspecting I was doing something wrong... can't say I find this behavior very intuitive though, even though most things in programming are 0-based.

Comment: It is even more unintuitive that the year and day parts do not seem to be 0-based...

Comment: @Kharlos - Day numbers are 0 based too - 0 = Sunday - one of those things - more info here: [Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Comment: days are 1 based instead. what kind of policy is that?

Comment: I do not understand your question

Answer (score 1):

No, you are using March, aren't you? 29th of March exists.

```
var myDate = new Date(2011, 1, 28); // 28th of february
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot, that it counts months from 0.
var myDate = new Date(2011, 2, 28);
is actually
Mon Mar 28 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time) {}

Try

```
 var myDate = new Date(2011, 1, 28);
 alert(myDate);
 myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
 alert(myDate); // 1 Mar 2011 !
```