# android calendar month begin at 0

Tags: java, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

It seems that calendar in android makes month begins from 0.
Why should it be designed like this?

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Today, the mMonth is 4.

Comment: This post discusses it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar. It's not specific to Anroid.

Comment: Yes, MONTH always begins from 0, you need to add +1 for getting current Month

Comment: I made a mistake. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This was not done by the Android developers. This is how it works in `java.util.Calendar`.
If you want to know why the Java developers designed it this way, please go through this thread.
[Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)