# DatePickerDialog listener - Month gets 0

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When selecting a date on DatePickerDialog the months gets 0. I used this same code past weeks. Date and Year are working fine.
I searched on Internet and everything seems alike tutorials.

```
fun datePick (context: Context, textView: TextView){
    var calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    var sday = calendar.get(android.icu.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    var smonth = calendar.get(android.icu.util.Calendar.MONTH)
    var syear = calendar.get(android.icu.util.Calendar.YEAR)

    var listener =DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
        sday = dayOfMonth
        smonth = month
        syear = year
        textView.text = "$sday/$month/$syear"  }

    var dialog =DatePickerDialog(context,listener,syear,smonth,sday)
    dialog.show()
}
```

Comment: What value are you expecting? Do note that months are zero-based; i.e., January is 0, February is 1, etc.

Comment: Duplicate of [android calendar month begin at 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10529102/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

In the Calendar class in Java, months are represented with a zero-based index (*January is 0, February is 1.. and so on*). This behavior is expected and you can easily adjust your code to blend with this behavior. For more information on why months are zero-based, read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/344380/5670752).

Note that **ONLY MONTHS** have this odd style of indexing. Days of the week, as well as the year, work normally as you'd expect.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!