# Java - Subtract Days from date

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm trying to subtract 5 days from a date which comes in as a string initially.

I have had a look at some of the other posts on this subject but the result i get from the code is always incorrect. The main problem is that the year value does not seem to change when the days are subtracted for example - `2012-01-01 subtract 5 days gives me 'Jan 27 2012'` using this code -

```
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -5);
```

Please help.

Comment: How are you parsing the string `2012-01-01` into a `Calendar`? I suspect you have an error there.

Answer (score 6):

Did you know that, in Java, month `1` is actually February?

```
Date februaryTheFirst = new Date(2012,1,1); // equals 2012-02-01
```

This might explain what you are seeing. If you want to instantiate 2012-01-01 instead, you should do:

```
Date firstDayOf2012 = new Date(2012,0,1); // this is 2012-01-01
```

Exactly the same thing happens when dealing with `Calendar`:

```
Calendar.getInstance().set(2012,0,1); // 2012-01-01
```

Be sure to check the documentation for [`Date(int, int, int)`](http://goo.gl/Bec8q) and [`Calendar.set(int, int, int)`](http://goo.gl/OPxCL). Also, you could check the way you are parsing the string. If you use [`SimpleDateFormat.parse(...)`](http://goo.gl/U3TNs), things can be easier.

Strange, isn't it? Go figure... Just as a fun fact, IntelliJ's documentation annotates this second parameter, month, with `@MagicConstant`, to remember the programmer that there's something very strange going on.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar.FEBRUARY is 1 and five days before 1 Feb 2012 was 27 Jab 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is correct and you are getting the correct value aslo.

`Calendar`'s Months started with `0`

```
0 = Jan
1 = Feb
```

so subtracting `5 days` from  `2012-01-01` will definitely returns you `Jan 27 2012`
something is here also which will helps you [Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

The Joda-Time 2.7 library makes this work much easier. Just call the `minusDays` method.

```
String input = "2012-01-01";
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, zone );
DateTime then = now.minusDays( 5 );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withZone( zone ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
String output = formatter.print( then );
```

If you want the beginning of the day, add a call to `withTimeAtStartOfDay`. This is unnecessary in your case, when parsing a date-only string with no time-of-day.

```
DateTime dateTimeAtStartOfDay = new DateTime( input, zone ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

If you want only date without time-of-day or time zone, use `LocalDate` instead of DateTime.

```
LocalDate then = new LocalDate( "2012-01-01" ).minusDays( 5 );
```

If you need to convert to the old java.util.Date, call `toDate` on the DateTime.

## java.time

Java 8 has a new package, java.time. These new classes were inspired by Joda-Time but were re-architected. Both java.time and Joda-Time can solve this particular problem equally well.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5)
```

EDIT: sorry. `DAY_OF_MONTH` is a synonym to `DATE`. Instead of `1` use `Calendar.JANUARY`.

Answer (score -1):

This a segment of code that is working on my pc. first you have to get the calendar instance the perform your calculation.

```
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     System.out.println("Today : " + cal.getTime());
    // Subtract 300 days from the calendar
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -300);
    System.out.println("300 days ago: " + cal.getTime());
```

This is the output that you will get:

```
    Today : Wed Oct 17 10:41:23 EET 2012
    300 days ago: Thu Dec 22 10:41:23 EET 2011
```