# How to substract two dates in GregorianCallendar?

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar

How to write a function which returns number of days between two dates in Gregorian Callendar? What type should I convert my dates and how?

```
public int substractDate(GregorianCalendar beginningDate, GregorianCalendar endingDate){
            return dif;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Subtract Days from date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930134/java-subtract-days-from-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GregorianCalendar object which is a subclass of Calendar:

```
    String dayPattern = "DD";
    SimpleDateFormat days = new SimpleDateFormat(dayPattern);
    return Integer.parseInt(days.format(endingDate.getTimeInMillis()-beginningDate.getTimeInMillis()));
```

[Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)