# calendar month and year before

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have to put a date one week before and then 1 month before. If i try with the days one week before is working but if the day es 5 and it has to change the month is not working, it changes me the year instead. About the month it changes me the year
tring addUrl = "";

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
    // surround below line with try catch block as below code throws checked
    // exception
    Date endDate = sdf.parse(request.getParameter(field.getId()));
    Calendar cal = DateToCalendar(endDate);
    cal.setTime(endDate);

    SimpleDateFormat formatToSend = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-mm-dd");

    case "day":
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

        addUrl = "startDate=" + formatToSend.format(cal.getTime()) + "&endDate=" + endDateString;
        break;

    case "week":
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -6); // number of days to add
        addUrl = "startDate=" + formatToSend.format(cal.getTime()) + "&endDate=" + endDateString;
        break;

    default:
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1); // number of days to add
        addUrl = "startDate=" + formatToSend.format(cal.getTime()) + "&endDate=" + endDateString;

    }
```

How i can do that?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Subtract Days from date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930134/java-subtract-days-from-date)

Answer (score 1):

In your `SimpleDateFormat` objects, you should use `MM` for months and not `mm`, because `mm` means **minutes**, not months.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

SimpleDateFormat formatToSend = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

See the API documentation of [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure do i fully understand the question however one potential problem is in your date format

m = **Minute** in hour

M = **Month** in year <- maybe the one you want?

See here for more examples.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html