# Weird behaviour of Calendar and DateFormat

Tags: java, date, formatting

I encountered really strange behaviour when constructing a Calendar object and then formating it in a particular style.

Let the code do the talking:

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SimpleDateFormat frmt = new SimpleDateFormat();
        frmt.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2012,1,1);
        System.out.println(frmt.format(date.getTime()));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
2012-02-01
```

The expected output is of course:

```
2012-01-01
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Months are zero based: January = 0, Feb = 1....

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I really do not know why are months zero based?

Comment: @Nejc the "why" has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar

Comment: @assylias Thanks! But I really feel it as counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Nejc It is hence my recommendation to use named constants - that way there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @assylias I am working on an interactive app, so the user inputs the year, month and day. I thought I would use the numerical representation to construct the date. Maybe I will create a new input method.

Comment: @Nejc You can still use `input - 1` if you get a numerical input.

Comment: Ofcourse! But I am considering to have an String input, which is formated as yyyy-MM-dd, and then use the formatter to parse string and construct a Calendar object.

Comment: You make this sound like it's such a big deal.  java's been like this since 1995.  Figure it out, like so many people before you have.  Counter-intuitive?  Not in C-world.

Comment: Maybe I make it sound, like it is a big deal. It isn't to me. But nevertheless, I figured it out and now I know. At least I should expect something like this from java, because it mixes everything together (0-based and 1-based structures).

Comment: I don't know why you brought C in the debate... I still think this is counter intuitieve (because in our world, january is the 1st month of the year, hence number 1). Because java is not as low-level as C, it would be simple to stick with the intuitive thing. Like this, it is also intuitive to me, that array indices start at 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Months start at 0, so `new GregorianCalendar(2012,1,1);` is the 1st of February. For 1st of January, you would use

```
new GregorianCalendar(2012,0,1);
// or even better 
new GregorianCalendar(2012,Calendar.JANUARY,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Month start with 0 in `GregorianCalendar`.

```
public static final int JANUARY = 0;
```

It is declared in Clanedar class. and for February it is 1. So update code -

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2012,Calendar.JANUARY,1);
```

or

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2012,0,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Month is 0-based. January == 0. From `Calendar#MONTH` javadoc:

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) if you dont want Months that are indexed at 0

Answer (score 0):

It is [documented behavior](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

> month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field in the calendar. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

It is advisable to use the constants in Calendar, eg `[Calendar.JANUARY][2]` when using this constructor.