# Calendar instance providing wrong week number when calendar built with basic fields

Tags: java, calendar, week-number

I would like to understand why this happens, and how can i solve this small issue.
I would like to be able to get the week number from a java calendar instance after providing the day, the month and the year.
if i do:

```
  Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 11);
       cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,2);
       cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
```

11 Feb 2013 is week 7, but if i invoke, in the above calendar instance:

```
int weekNumber=cal.get(Calendar.week_of_year)
```

I get the week number 11.
Any idea why?
I tried setting the locale but no difference, the problem is that i can only build a calendar out of these three fields, since i'm reading them from a xml file with a parser and they are in format dd-mm-yyyy with no more information that that

Comment: For some background and deeper undertanding as to why and alternatives also read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months fields in `Calendar` are zero based. The value `2` corresponds to [Calendar.MARCH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MARCH). To avoid confusion, better to use the `Calendar` constants. You could use:

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used March, because Java months in [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) are 0-based: 0 = January, 1 = February, 2 = March.

Use

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,1);
```

or

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
```

if you can use a constant.  Else, subtract 1 from the month you received from your parser.