# onSelectedDayChange from CalendarView retrieves the month wrong?

Tags: android, calendarview

Ok, this might sound like a silly question but I'm just surprise of it happening; it seems like when you click on a day in a CalendarView, the month given from

```
 onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
```

is not the one that it could be expected, because Januar is month=0, Februar is month=1 and so on. 
Am I the only one getting this result? Does anyone know the reason for this behaviour?

Of course, in order to print it or do something with the month, I can just increase it, but it seems just weird... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's define like that.

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener.html) :

> `public abstract void onSelectedDayChange (CalendarView view, int year,
>   int month, int dayOfMonth)`
>
> `Added in API level 11 Called upon change of the selected day.`
>
> `Parameters` 
> `view :The view associated with this listener.`
>   
> `year : The year that was set.` 
> `month : The month that was set`
>   **[0-11]**.
>  `dayOfMonth :   The day of the month that was set.`

You could see it at the values defined for the constants [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH).

You could see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar) why the months constants starts from 0 to 11.

Comment: Hey thanks, I didn't know this decision came from the Calendar. :)

Comment: Where would be the fun if this kind of API would respect the way humans and programmers think.