# Date gets added to the DB but with month incremented by one. Why is that?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, calendar

I take in the date from the `html` field as `date/month/year`. If the input is :

```
01/07/2013
```

the date in the `mysql` database goes as `2013-08-01`. Thus the month gets incremented by one. Why is that ?

Following snippet inserts the date to the DB from html field.

```
        String dateMonthYear[] = issueDate.split("/");

        System.out.println("DATE MONT YEAR-------> "+dateMonthYear[1]);
        // PRINTS THE CORRECT MONTH

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dateMonthYear[2]));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateMonthYear[1]));
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateMonthYear[0]));
        Date issueDateDB = cal.getTime();

        issued.setDateOfIssue(issueDateDB);

        // commit operation
```

The type of the corresponding type in the `db` is `Date` . What could be the reason that moth gets incremented by `one` ?

Comment: just print issueDateDB  is coming proper

Comment: @shreyanshjogi yeah..`issuedDateDB.getTime` prints `Jul 1, 2013 12:42:51 PM`

Answer (score 2):

This is because [`Calendar.MONTH` is 0-based](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) (`Calendar.JANUARY = 0`, and so on). Add 1 to the month part when writing to the database, substract 1 when reading from it.

I recommend reading this [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/344400/1446005) to a similar question.

Comment: but you see..`issuedDateDB.getTime` prints `Jul 1, 2013 12:42:51 PM` and not `Aug 1,2013`. Why is it so ?

Comment: But you see, you're set'ting a value of 1..12, but the API is expecting a value of 0..11.  RandomSeed is correct.  And Shreyansh Jogi is suggesting a different ... perhaps better ... approach of using SimpleDateFormat().parse().

Comment: @paulsm4 _"..you're set'ting a value of 1..12, but the API is expecting a value of 0..11.."_ I didn't get you. The point is just before inserting the date to the db,the month is `july` !

Comment: @SuhailGupta That's interesting... What is the output of just `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1); System.out.println(cal.getTime());` ? Here I get "Fri **Feb** 01 (...)".

Comment: @RandomSeed same..`Fri Feb 01 13:55:17 IST 2013`

Comment: @SuhailGupta Then you must be initialising your `cal` variable in a different way. I executed your code snippet with `issueDate = "01/07/2013"` and `cal.getTime()` returns "Thu **Aug** 01 (...)".

Answer (score 1):

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/07/2013");
```

try this instead

Answer (score 0):

Just because calender's month starts with 0 not from 1 ex:- for january value of month is 0 not 1 .so you have to decrease month by -1.