# Get 1 month ago from current datetime

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to get 1 month ago date and time but what i get from this was 2013 11 02 which the correct one should be 2013 12 02 pls help.

My Code as below :-

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

    int thisYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int thisMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int thisDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: It may help to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH they are zero indexed so your code is correct, you just have to understand how to read the value

Comment: Constants values start from 0 i.e. o for January and 11 for december

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is correct, I think the months are zero indexed ;)

Try this,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
String dateOutput = format.format(date);
```

This should interpret the date values for you in logical units rather than the internal representation

Checkout out documentation for [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for a more custom approach, I just made some assumptions based on your question text.

Comment: Oh like you want it to print the word january? you could use a lookup table that maps Calendar.JANUARY -> "January" or just use a SimpleDateFormatter and pass it the date that the Calendar object represents

Comment: It should, try it, `calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);` `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);` `calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);`

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JANUARY){
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.DECEMBER);
    }else{
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1);
    }

    int thisYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int thisMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int thisDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: You can't do `calendar.YEAR-1`. This makes no sense. YEAR is a static member of the Calendar class. YEAR is a constant. To subtract 1 from it makes no sense since it is just a key to look up a value from

Comment: this code return result 2014-11-2 00:00:00. I should get 2013-12-02 00:00:00

Comment: I have edited this answer after running it successfully try it now