# Oracle ATG Scheduler: Month oddity

Tags: java, atg, atg-dynamo

The basic usage for the ATG scheduler(added as a property in your ATG properties file):

```
schedule=calendar mos dates wkdays mo-occurs hrs mins
```

The docs for this are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0905schedulesettings01.html#s0905calendarschedule01).

The description for the month(mos) is extremely baffling to me:

```
Parameter | Values | Description 

mos       | 0..11  | The months when the task occurs, where 0 represents December.
```

Is there any valid reason for this bizarre break from normal month representation, ie 1-12?

I am at a loss to understand why they did this. It doesn't even line up with the way `java.util.Calendar` behaves: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Is there some logical explanation as to why they did this?

Comment: So, this question is about why they decide to select this value for December? Who knows, I think only ATG starters could ask:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a typing error. In the older docs for [ATG 2007](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23507_01/Platform.20073/ATGProgGuide/html/s0905configuringaschedulablecomponent01.html) it correctly refers to January as 0 and December as 11. Additionally the rest of the content on that page indicates that May is 4 and August is 7 (only true if January is 0). This seems to have crept into the documentation somewhere between 2007 and ATG 9. It is still incorrect in ATG 10.2/ATG 11 documentation

Comment: Bizarre that something THAT obvious could be changed and no one would catch it...

Comment: Maybe when they started using Joda Time for a few of their date/time functions they got confused and decided to let the rest of us feel the same.