# why do I get wrong month when parsing with java calendar

Tags: java, timer, calendar

```
Date fakeDate = sdf.parse("15/07/2013 11:00 AM");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.setTime(fakeDate);
int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

I get currentMonth == 6 instead of 7.

why is that?

Comment: While the question has been answered, the good solution is to drop the outdated `Calendar` class and use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), instead. It is so much nicer to work with, and it numbers months the same way humans do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Calendar.MONTH` is ZERO based. [Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)?

Check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH): (always)

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a
>   calendar-specific value. **The first month of the year in the Gregorian
>   and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0**; the last depends on the
>   number of months in a year.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun You are very fast. +1 for your quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

As the doc says - *Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.*

So try something like this

```
int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
```

Because
    `calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)` shall give you (currentMonthValue-1) as the value of january starts with 0

Answer (score 0):

It should be

`int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;`

Comment: But why? Your answer doesn't really help OP, please elaborate more to get my +1.