# Calendar class time month not matching

Tags: java, calendar

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.println("Mili->>" + c.getTimeInMillis());

System.out.println("Month  ->>" + Calendar.MONTH);
```

Though I am getting correct time in millisec format, Month is showing as 2 (March??) Why so?

Below is output

> Mili->>1434029840778
>
> Month  ->>2

Comment: month start with 0. read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar

Comment: @ Fast Snail yes it starts with 0, but in june it should show 5 right ?

Comment: are you telling that you get `Calendar.MONTH` as 2 for march or as 2 for june ??

Comment: in June it showed 2, got the answer now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the following idiom: `c.get(Calendar.MONTH)`.

`Calendar.MONTH` per se is just an internal constant and will (hopefully) always return `2`.

**Example**

```
// We're in June at the time of writing
// Months are 0-based so June == 5
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(Calendar.MONTH);
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

**Output**

```
2
5
```

See also: [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29)

Comment: i am getting the compile time error "The method get(int) is undefined for the type String" when i am using c.get(Calendar.MONTH)

Comment: You need to use `System.out.println("Month  ->>" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH));` , **not** `System.out.println(c.get("Month  ->>" + Calendar.MONTH));`!

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying the value of the `Calendar.MONTH` constant, hence 2.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting calendar c from an instance but calendar from month with the Calendar object, get it from the instance too.

Also - Calendar starts from 0 as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

In other news, use the new DateTime API in Java 8 or JODA time, they're much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
int monthNumber = LocalDate.now().getMonth().getValue() ;  // 1-12 for January-December.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The other Answers are outmoded. The terribly flawed legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar` & `Date` were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

If you want a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds, use `java.time.Instant` class.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = Instant.now().toMillis() ;
```

Going the other direction:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofMillis( millisSinceEpoch ) ;
```

If you want to know the month, you must specify the time zone by which you want to determine the date. For any given moment, the time and date varies around the globe by time zone. Therefore the month can vary too.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Interrogate for the month, an enum object [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html).

```
Month month = zdt.getMonth() ;
```

Get the month number by asking the enum object for is definition order. Unlike the legacy `Calendar` class, *java.time* uses sane numbering: 1-12 for January-December. So March is 3, as you expected.

```
int monthNumber = month.getValue() ;
```

If you want to skip the count of milliseconds, and just want to know the current month, use `LocalDate` to capture the current date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
Month currentMonth = today.getMonth() ;
int monthNumber = currentMonth.getValue() ;
```

Or, collapse that code:

```
int monthNumber = 
    LocalDate
    .now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) )
    .getMonth()
    .getValue() ;
```