# Incorect Date to String convertation in Java

Tags: java, android

Why code return string value is 19880420 instead of 19880320?

```
SimpleDateFormat template= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(1988, 3, 20, 18, 00);

return template.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because January is month 0 so you have to do -1 when constructing your calendar
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH

Answer (score 2):

Month beginns with 0 not with 1. :)

Have a look here:
[Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)