# Calendar - Get last day of previous month

Tags: java, android

I want to get the last day of the previous month.
But this doesnt seem to work:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Integer lastDay = cal.getInstance().getActualMaximum(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH);

cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

Integer prevMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
Integer prevMonthYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
Integer lastDayPrevMonth = cal.getInstance().getActualMaximum(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH);

System.out.println("Previous month was: " + prevMonth + "-" + prevMonthYear);
System.out.println("Last day in previous month was: " + lastDayPrevMonth);
System.out.println("Last day in this month is: " + lastDay);
```

This outputs:

```
I/System.out﹕: Previous month was 10-2015
I/System.out﹕: Last day in previous month was 31
I/System.out﹕: Last day in this month is 31
```

So it's getting the previous month, that's november (10), giving that it is now december (11).
Last day in this month is also correct, but clearly, last day in previous month was not 31, but 30.

Why does the second `getActualMaximum` give the same "last-day-in-month" as the first, when I do the add -1 thing?

Comment: This might help some users http://stackoverflow.com/a/344400/3701433

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem in your current code is that you are calling multiple times the `Calendar.getInstance()` method, which returns the current date.

To obtain a `Calendar` which is the last day of the previous month, you can have the following:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

It subtracts one month from the current month and sets the day of month to its maximum value, obtained with [`getActualMaximum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum-int-). Note that the month is 0-based in `Calendar` so January is actually 0.

Comment: This case will fail when we try from January. Year will be wrong.

Answer (score 11):

You can use LocalDate as below:

```
LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Solved my problem

Comment: `LocalDate` was introduced in Java 1.8 (just for record for poor users of Java 7).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think it will solve your problem:

```
/**
 * Returns previous month date in string format
 * @param date
 * @return
 */
private static String getPreviousMonthDate(Date date){
    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
    cal.setTime(date);  
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

    Date preMonthDate = cal.getTime();  
    return format.format(preMonthDate);
}

/**
 * Returns previous to previous month date in string format
 * @param date
 * @return
 */
private static String getPreToPreMonthDate(Date date){
    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
    cal.setTime(date);  
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);  
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);  
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);  

    Date preToPreMonthDate = cal.getTime();  
    return format.format(preToPreMonthDate);
}
```