# How to display last day of previous month relative to a date?

Tags: java, date, jasper-reports

I have created several variables with time-expressions, to create time-based reports:

```
// First of month (Returns 01/09/2017)
 new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(java.util.Date.parse("01/" + MONTH(NOW( )) + "/" + YEAR(NOW())))

// First of previous month (Returns 01/08/2017)
 new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(java.util.Date.parse("01/" + (MONTH(NOW( )) - 1) + "/" + YEAR(NOW())))

// Last of month (Returns 30/09/2017)
 new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(java.util.Date.parse(MONTH(NOW( )) + "/" + DAYSINMONTH(NOW())+ "/" + YEAR(NOW())))
```

I am now struggling with getting the last day of the previous month. I tried something like below, but of course this does not work properly, as not all months have the same amount of days.

```
// Last of previous month (Returns 30/08/2017)
 new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(java.util.Date.parse(
  (MONTH(NOW( )) - 1)
  + "/" +
  DAYSINMONTH(NOW())
  + "/" +
  YEAR(NOW())
 ))
```

Do you know of a way to retrieve the last (day) of the previous month?

reference: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/843248/last-day-current-month

Comment: I recently realized it by using a SQL case in the select statement. Still interested in clever solutions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I would probably have solved this creating a static class in java with a method that takes the date as parameter and then use the [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) api or similar to return to the desired date, this is how to do it in java [Calendar - Get last day of previous month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076518/calendar-get-last-day-of-previous-month).*

**However, lets have fun and use only jasper-reports**

Since we can't use Calendar api (it returns void) we need to fall back [again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37579395/5292302) on the [`org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) as my friend [Tunaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki) taught me.

Using `DateUtils` we can call first `truncate` with month (remove days) and then we `addDays` -1 (-1 day if we are at first date of month it will give us the last date of previous month)

```
DateUtils.addDays(DateUtils.truncate(myDate, Calendar.MONTH),-1);
```

## jrxml example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="DateUtil" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f288086f-db4e-451f-bf32-e1cce6311a27">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <import value="java.util.Calendar"/>
    <import value="org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils"/>
    <parameter name="date" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="220" height="20" uuid="48878c52-5527-4784-a74a-e2d8df65cc55"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[DateUtils.addDays(DateUtils.truncate($P{date}, Calendar.MONTH),-1)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

## Output (the day I passed this answer)

[image: result]

> **Design note**: You should use pattern to format the Date as I do in my example, do not use `SimpleDateFormat` in expression, using pattern will give you correct object if you export for example to excel.