# Date Pattern starting from 12 hours

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I'm trying to convert two dates into this pattern: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

I need to retrieve two dates:

- Last year, same month, day 1, 00:00:00.000
- Last day of previous month, 23:59:59.999

So, as of today, I need these two values:

- `2022-11-01 00:00:00.000`
- `2023-10-31 23:59:59.999`

The problem is: I get `2022-11-01 12:00:00.000`.

This is the code that generates last year's date.

```
private String getLastYear() {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return format.format(c.getTime());
}
```

If I try adding one hour, the output will be: `2022-11-01 13:00:00.000`.

Also, I can't retrieve the last day of the previous month. As I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34076758/11961036), all I keep getting is the first day of the next month.

Here's the code.

```
private String getPreviousMonth() {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = new Date();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
    return format.format(c.getTime());
}
```

There is something I'm missing.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `LocalDateTime` should be used instead of `Date`, and should make it easier.

Comment: I may consider using `LocalDateTime`, but still, I'm manually setting hours, minutes etc. I just don't understand why it's not working as intended. I'm not a newbie.

Comment: [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) package was added because classes `Date` and `Calendar` are problematic. Why do you prefer to use `Date` and `Calendar` (and `SimpleDateFormat`) rather than `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: Because, before this, I didn't know `Calendar` and `Date` were so inconsistent. I learned something.

Comment: You are getting 12:00:00 because you are using Calendar.HOUR, which represents an AM/PM time.  You need to use Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY instead.

Comment: @VGR thank you so much! This is the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say *any help is highly appreciated*, so here's an example that uses `java.time`, which uses *today* as base and calculates the two desired results as follows:

###### First of current month in the last year

- subtract a year from today (`2023-11-17` ⇒ `2022-11-17`)
- take the first of that month (`2022-11-17` ⇒ `2022-11-01`)
- involve the start of the day (`2022-11-01` ⇒ `2022-11-01 00:00:00.000`)

###### Last day of last month at the end of the day

- subtract a month from today (`2023-11-17` ⇒ `2023-10-17`)
- go to the last day of that month (`2023-10-17` ⇒ `2023-10-31`)
- append the maximum time of day (`2023-10-31` ⇒ `2023-10-31 23:59:59.999`)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime lastYearSameMonthFirstDay
                        // today (without time of day)
                        = LocalDate.now()
                                   // subtract 1 from the year
                                   .minusYears(1)
                                   // go to the first day of month 
                                   .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())
                                   // append the start of the day
                                   .atStartOfDay();
    
    LocalDateTime lastDayOfPreviousMonth
                        // today (date only as above)
                        = LocalDate.now()
                                   // subract 1 from the month value
                                   .minusMonths(1)
                                   // go to the last day of that month
                                   .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())
                                   // append the end of the day
                                   .atTime(LocalTime.MAX);
    // prepare a formatter for the output
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    // and print both LocalDateTimes formatted as desired
    System.out.println(lastYearSameMonthFirstDay.format(dtf));
    System.out.println(lastDayOfPreviousMonth.format(dtf));
}
```

Output (execution date 2023-11-17):

```
2022-11-01 00:00:00.000
2023-10-31 23:59:59.999
```

Comment: Trying ASAP! Thank you for the effort

Comment: `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`, is `uuuu` a typo or is it actually a pattern?

Comment: It's not a typo, there's `yyyy`, too, in `java.time`, but it's year of era there… No need to mess with era ;-) But the difference would rarely impact the result in your case, I think.

Comment: The string I'm generating will be inserted in a SQL Server `PreparedStatement`. Do you think `uuuu` format is more errorproof?

Comment: Works smooth! Thank you so much again for your precious.. time!

Comment: Yes. `TemporalAdjusters` is the way to go.

Comment: @deHaar, you have a typo in your arrow entity!  ... `&rArr`.

Comment: @Marco if that is intended for SQL, it is recommended to use the respective date/time objects and not Strings

Comment: @Reilas Thanks, I forgot the `;`… now it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I need to retrieve two dates:*
>
> - *Last year, same month, day 1, 00:00:00.000*
> - *Last day of previous month, 23:59:59.999 ..."*

Here is an example.

```java
import static java.util.Calendar.*;
```

```java
Calendar a, b;
a = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
a.set(YEAR, a.get(YEAR) - 1);
a.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
a.set(HOUR, 0);
a.set(MINUTE, 0);
a.set(SECOND, 0);
a.set(MILLISECOND, 0);
b = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
b.add(MONTH, -1);
b.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, b.getActualMaximum(DAY_OF_MONTH));
b.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
b.set(MINUTE, 59);
b.set(SECOND, 59);
b.set(MILLISECOND, 999);
```

> *"... Also, I can't retrieve the last day of the previous month. As I have read here, all I keep getting is the first day of the next month. ..."*

Use the *[getActualMaximum](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum(int))* method.

> *"... I'm trying to convert two dates into this pattern: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`. ..."*

Optionally, you can use basic format specifiers here.
There is a full list in the *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#ddt)* *JavaDoc*.

```java
System.out.printf("%tF %<tT.%<tL%n", a.getTime());
System.out.printf("%tF %<tT.%<tL%n", b.getTime());
```

Output

```
2022-11-01 00:00:00.000
2023-10-31 23:59:59.999
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but your code is just like mine. I used the same functions to achieve the same goal. I don't receive the output I need (and that you specified), which is exactly the purpose of this question: why is this not working properly? Anyway, I solved using LocalDateTime. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @MarcoFragDelleMonache, possibly a different version of _Java_?  I don't see why, otherwise.

Comment: I'm using Java 8, but probably the only difference is that you use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` instead of `Calendar.HOUR`

Comment: @MarcoFragDelleMonache, one of your requirements was to have a value of, _"2023-10-31 23:59:59.999"_.  This requires _HOUR_OF_DAY_, and not _HOUR_.  I believe, unless I've overlooked something.

Comment: Indeed, yours it the right way to do that