# Month value doesn't correspond to actual months

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    var newDate = new Date( 2016 , 2 , 28 , 8 , 0 , 0 , 0 );
    alert( $.fn.jquery );
    $('#countdown-ex1').countdown({until: newDate});
});
```

results in:

[image]

---

where as

```
var newDate = new Date( 2016 , 1 , 28 , 8 , 0 , 0 , 0 );
```

results in:

[image]

jQuery Version: 1.11.3

---

TL;DR;

Month 2 equals March

Month 1 equals February

Now is this a bug or on purpose? **And why would that be on purpose?**

Comment: Month values are zero based, ie. `0` = Jan, `1` = Feb...

Comment: Yes, they are 0 based.... Surely you should have realized this on your own.

Comment: @TravisJ why would they be 0 based if the year and day isn't that's what I don't get

Comment: I think this answer explain this well. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179285/why-does-javascript-treat-days-and-months-differently

Comment: One reason would be that days and years have no names. Whereas months do. So that means binding months to a 0 based indexed array of names is straight forward. That and many other explanations here from Jon Skeet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/344400/1026459; however, the general outlook there is "don't worry about the why". Also, this is a topic which has been covered many times, there are several duplicates on the site, and it is easily googleable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Month values are zero based, ie. `0` = Jan, `1` = Feb, and so on. To get the dates you expect just reduce the Month values by 1:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    var newDate = new Date( 2016 , 1 , 28 , 8 , 0 , 0 , 0 ); // 28 Feb 2016
    alert( $.fn.jquery );
    $('#countdown-ex1').countdown({until: newDate});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Read some documentation on JS Date objects:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

particularly the bit about months being 0 to 11..

Answer (score -1):

date's month is on 0 base.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

> The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.