# Why does java takes my month as 1 month behind

Tags: java, calendar

I'm trying to code a clock in java and for april it says 3 instead of 4 why is that?

here is my code

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

Comment: It's 0-11 for Months i.e 0 => Jan to 11 => Dec

Comment: Sarah Jane: as a minimum, you should read the relevant javadocs before asking questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the month January in java is "0"

Refer to this question if you wanna know what it is "0"

[Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar][1])

Comment: Thanks this explains a lot