# Set Calendar with specific date and get wrong values for month

Tags: java, android, date, android-calendar, java.util.calendar

I am using this method to set time to the calendar but when I want to get month it'll give me month-1.

For example when I set  "2017-12-27 10:50:00". And when I want to get the month of the calendar it's 11 instead of 12.

```
   public String setDate(String gDate){

       try {

           private final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

           Date date = sdf.parse(gDate);
           javaCalendar.setTime(date);

       } catch (ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           Log.i("LOG_DATE", "Error is: " + e.toString());
       }
       return "";
   }
```

Comment: It starts with 0. it is 0 to 11.

Comment: share you code to get calendar month

Comment: Even on Android, consider dropping the old classes `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` and using `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` from JSR-310, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. And will give you the 12th month as either `Month.DECEMBER` or 12, you choose. To use JSR-310 on Android, add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because The Months are numbered from 0 (January) to 11 (December)

for more visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/344400/5602752