# Groovy: DateUtil.format "yyyy-MM-dd" increments month by one while formatting

Tags: java, date, groovy

In my groovy test case below i have certain date objects which later i am formatting using `DateUtil.format(calendarObj,"yyyy-MM-dd")`.
But when i print the result, it increments the month by 1.

For Example:

Groovy Code:

```
def testDate=new GregorianCalendar(2000,1,30);
def testDate1=new GregorianCalendar(2000,1,5);
def testDate2=new GregorianCalendar(2000,4,25);
def testDate3=new GregorianCalendar(2000,6,10);
```

Output (using `System.out.println(DateUtil.format(testDate/1/2/3,"yyyy-MM-dd"))`):

```
2000-03-01
2000-02-05
2000-05-25
2000-07-10
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening.

Comment: Curiously, in the first example you are creating the `February 30th` (it doesn't exist) and in the formatting you are getting `March 1st`.

Comment: @Hector: Not that curious at all. 2000 was a leap year were february had 29 days. So by setting the value to 30-february the calendar will automatically change the month to march and day to 1. In the same way that setting it to 32-january would result in a date that actually is the 1. february.

Comment: That's a really bad design for me. What do you think?

Comment: You are using troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: Related: [Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Comment: The good solution is to use `java.time` (as mentioned) and `LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 30)`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Months in Java (and by extension Groovy) are zero-based, so January is `0`, February is `1`, etc.

As noted in the comments, this is only the case for the original Java date/time classes ([`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), ...).

For classes in the (preferred) new date/time API that was introduced in Java 8 ([`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), ...), this behavior was changed to be more intuitive.

Comment: Nice hat you got there

Comment: Not "in Java". In GregorianCalendar. The javax.time API, which should be preferred over this old ugly GregorianCalendar, uses 1-based months.

Comment: @JBNizet Will update my answer.

Comment: Oh, thank you all, got it now

Comment: Example: `LocalDate.of( 2000 , 1 , 30 ).toString()` where 1-12 means January-December. Or better, use `Month` enum: `LocalDate.of( 2000 , Month.JANUARY , 30 ).toString()`